# How to Produce an Actual Encrypted Files with AES? [JAVA]

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Hi i have explore many good site about AES Encryption, Most Site will be nicely detail about how to encrypt files and really help me understand the AES Encryption.

but i am still unclear about how to produce files that is encrypted. this [tutorial example](http://aesencryption.net/) explain how AES encryption was done but i still cannot see the physical encrypted file. Most example show only how to encrypt and decrypt but did not explain about how to produce encrypted physical file.

My Question here is how do we actually produce an actual encrypted files, i believe this question is relevance to SO citizen as this might help other in future.

**Answer**
The code below will encrypt a text file with physical encrypted file.

```
final Path origFile = Paths.get("C:\\3.txt");
final byte[] contents = Files.readAllBytes(origFile);

// Get the KeyGenerator

   KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
   kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available


// Generate the secret key specs.
   SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
   byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

   SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");


// Instantiate the cipher

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

   byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(contents.toString().getBytes());

   System.out.println("encrypted string: " + encrypted.toString());

   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
   byte[] original =cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

   String originalString = new String(original);
   System.out.println("Original string: " +originalString);

   final Path newFile = Paths.get("C:\\3encrypted.aes");
   Files.write(newFile, encrypted, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

     }
```

As fge suggest, this is not suite for encrypting large file. ill provide new answer when i done with my research.

Comment: Well, just write the resulting byte array from encryption into a file... Tried anything along those lines yet?

Comment: @fge,by file you mean text file right?

Comment: No, certainly not! You don't encrypt text, you encrypt bytes, always. And what those bytes will be when you deal with text will depend on what character encoding the text uses

Comment: I am sorry but i still dont get it, after i have encrypt the bytes, what am i suppose to do to physically produce an encrypted files after that?

Comment: this encrypted file will be used to prevent people from opening my work files (txt, doc, exe).

Comment: Uhwell, use `Files.write()` for instance. I don't really understand what your problem is to be honest.

Comment: @beNice: you create a FileOutputStream, and write the byte array to this stream. Read the IO tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: @JBNizet uhm, better to link to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) for Java 7+ users ;)

Comment: @beNice: You can get a detailed example from here http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/24/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-files-in-java-with-aes-in-cbc-mode-using-bouncy-castle-api-and-netbeans-or-eclipse/

Comment: appreciate you guys help, when i am ready with the answer ill update here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct; you try and read bytes from a file and then put it into a `StringBuffer` which is a *character sequence*. Don't do that!

Read the bytes directly:

```
final Path origFile = Paths.get("C:\\3.txt");
final byte[] contents = Files.readAllBytes(origFile);
```

Then encrypt like you do, and write your `encrypted` byte array into a new file:

```
final Path newFile = Paths.get("C:\\3encrypted.aes"); // or another name
Files.write(newFile, encrypted, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

---

It is very important to understand that *`String` is not suitable for binary data*. Please see [this link](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) for more details.

Comment: you have no idea how many hours i had struggle for the solution. You have save me and perhap many other.

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Note though that this solution is not tenable for very large files; in this case you have to use another set of methods. I don't know the Java encryption API too well but I am sure this is doable as well. And read the provided link! It might save you in more than one way!